# Calculate Combination based on position

Tags: c++, combinations, combinatorics

I have combinations like this:

1,2,3,4   //index 0
1,2,3,5   //index 1
1,2,3,6   //index 2

and so on until  7,8,9,10

So this will be n=10 k=4 from combinatorics

How calculate combination by index

For example when my index==1
myCmb = func(index)
returns 1,2,3,5

this is example i need this for bigest numbers, and for more params and without (if this possible) many loops

i find something like this to obtain position:
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110320070039AA045ib

I want now reverse this...

I programming in C++
Thanks for any sugesstions or help

Comment: How big are your "biggest" numbers? How many are "many" loops?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but the answer to this question is there somewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question. If you want to include more information in your question, please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5955503/edit). If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to [find the k-combination for a given number](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Finding_the_k-combination_for_a_given_number).

Following the [example](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Example), here's something that should work:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp>


std::size_t Choose(double n, double k) {
  using boost::math::binomial_coefficient;
  if (n < k) return 0;
  return static_cast<std::size_t>(binomial_coefficient<double>(n, k));
}

// Returns the largest n such that Choose(n, k) <= pos.
int CombinationElement(int k, int pos) {
  int n = k;
  int coeff = 1, prev_coeff = 0;

  while (coeff <= pos) {
    coeff = Choose(++n, k);
    prev_coeff = coeff;
  }

  return n - 1;
}

// Returns an k-combination at position pos.
std::vector<int> Combination(int k, int pos) {
  std::vector<int> combination;
  for (; k > 0; --k) {
    int n = CombinationElement(k, pos);
    combination.push_back(n);
    pos -= Choose(n, k);
  }
  return combination;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;

  if (argc != 3) {
    cout << "Usage:  $ " << argv[0] << " K POS" << endl;
    cout << "Prints the K-combination at position POS." << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  int k = boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[1]);
  int pos = boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[2]);

  std::vector<int> combination = Combination(k, pos);

  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    cout << combination[i] << " ";
  cout << std::endl;
}
```

Note, for convenience, the code depends on [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) to calculate binomial coefficients (`boost::math::binomial_coefficient<T>`), and to parse strings into integers (`boost::lexical_cast`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation in Mathematica, from the package [*Combinatorica*](http://www.combinatorica.com/).  The semantics are fairly generic, so I think it is helpful.  Please leave a comment if you need anything explained.

```
UnrankKSubset::usage = "UnrankKSubset[m, k, l] gives the mth k-subset of set l, listed in lexicographic order."

UnrankKSubset[m_Integer, 1, s_List] := {s[[m + 1]]}
UnrankKSubset[0, k_Integer, s_List] := Take[s, k]
UnrankKSubset[m_Integer, k_Integer, s_List] := 
       Block[{i = 1, n = Length[s], x1, u, $RecursionLimit = Infinity}, 
             u = Binomial[n, k]; 
             While[Binomial[i, k] < u - m, i++]; 
             x1 = n - (i - 1); 
             Prepend[UnrankKSubset[m - u + Binomial[i, k], k-1, Drop[s, x1]], s[[x1]]]
       ]
```

Usage is like:

```
UnrankKSubset[1, 4, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]
```

```
   {1, 2, 3, 5}
```

As you can see this function operates on sets.

---

Below is my attempt to explain the code above.

#### UnrankKSubset is a recursive function with three arguments, called (m, k, s):

1. `m` an Integer, the "rank" of the combination in lexigraphical order, starting from zero.
2. `k` an Integer, the number of elements in each combination
3. `s` a List, the elements from which to assemble combinations

#### There are two boundary conditions on the recursion:

1. for any rank `m`, and any list `s`, if the number of elements in each combination `k` is `1`, then:

   return the `m + 1` element of the list `s`, itself in a list.

   (`+ 1` is needed because Mathematica indexes from one, rather than zero.  I believe in C++ this would be s[m] )
2. if rank `m` is `0` then for any `k` and any `s`:

   return the first `k` elements of `s`

#### The main recursive function, for any other arguments than ones specified above:

local variables: (`i`, `n`, `x1`, `u`)

`Binomial` is binomial coefficient:  `Binomial[7, 5]` = 21

Do:

```
i = 1
n = Length[s]
u = Binomial[n, k]
While[Binomial[i, k] < u - m, i++];
x1 = n - (i - 1);
```

Then return:

```
Prepend[
  UnrankKSubset[m - u + Binomial[i, k], k - 1, Drop[s, x1]], 
  s[[x1]]
]
```

That is, "prepend" the `x1` element of list `s` (remember Mathematica indexes from one, so I believe this would be the `x1 - 1` index in C++) to the list returned by the recursively called UnrankKSubset function with the arguments:

- `m - u + Binomial[i, k]`
- `k - 1`
- `Drop[s, x1]`

`Drop[s, x1]` is the rest of list `s` with the first `x1` elements removed.

---

If anything above is not understandable, or if what you wanted was an explanation of the algorithm, rather than an explanation of the code, please leave a comment and I will try again.

Comment: I don't use mathematica i need write this as c++ function can you know how this gonna be in c++ ?

Comment: @josh, I am sorry, I only know Mathematica.  I was hoping that since this Mathematica code is primarily procedural, rather than functional, it would translate to C/C++ well enough.  Would you like me to try explaining the code above, step by step?

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna look at this and try to write this in C++, if im gonna be have any questions i ask you again.. for explanation, but this looks clear. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I find other solution written in C++